# Mongoose not returning deleted object in an populate array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have an array contains objectId referring to another scheme, and I use mongoose `populate` those objects to get a nested array. However, if one of the object in that array is removed form the database (but the obejctId is still remain the the array), when mongoose doing the `populate` process, it would skip that document, and the returning array is shorter than expected.

I am thinking if it is possible to ask mongoose to return `null` for non-exsited object, so the client could receive the array with expected length and notified the missing object in the array?

Comment: Not with `.populate()` since that is not how it works. You "can" do this by doing the same thing that `.populate()` is actually doing though, and running an `$in` query on the other collection and simply marking any un-matched `ObjectId` values in the parent as `null` where no result was found. The usual expectancy is that you would "clean up" your unresolvable references in the source array at the time of removal from the target, or vice versa.

Comment: For a better understanding, turn on debugging with `mongoose.set("debug",true)` since it's often a revelation to people when they find out what `.populate()` actually does.

Comment: I am very appreciate for your answers. I know it is better to clean up the non-existed object from their reference, however if I have multiple scheme contains fields that hold the reference to an object, won't it be a inefficient move to deleted all the unresolvable references in all the documents? Or is there any other way to 'clean up' more efficiently?

Comment: @MingtianYang I know it happened five years ago :) but how did you solve it? I am facing the same issue